# Why variable profile_id is displaying duality in controller and view template in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a function in my controller which is trying to fetch the value from view template and print the same through post method but something else is printing on there.

```
public function editProfile(){
    $profile = $this->input->post('profile');
    echo ("PROFILE:" . $profile);
}
```

This is my view template which is taking profile id from the application_info array stored in the database and matching it with the other profiles id so that the value of the particular id can be fetched and display out to the user-side using form.

```
$profile_id = $application_info[0]->profile_id;

<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>Job_profiles/editProfile" method="post" id="editApplication" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="profile">Profile</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="profile" name="profile">
        <option value="0">Select profile</option>
        <?php
        if(!empty($profiles))
        {
            foreach ($profiles as $p)
            {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $p->profile; ?>" <?php if($p->profile_id == $profile_id) {echo "selected=selected";} ?>><?php echo $p->profile ?></option>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

While printing the value of the variable inside the view template, everything is going fine. But when displaying the value through the controller, it prints nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: What is printed? We should guess or you'll explain?

Comment: @u_mulder echo $profile_id showing the id of the variable inside the view template. but when fetching the same variable through post in a controller, it prints nothing.